# Phonegaph Pushbots Plugin: How to get device registration id from google cloud messaging?

Tags: cordova, plugins, notifications, push, pushbots

I am using PushBots plugin in my Phonegap application for android phones. I need to get the device registration id from google cloud messaging server to send user specific push notification. I am using PHP and mySQL in back-end. Basically I need to save the device registration id to mysql db once the device is ready. Please help me to get a solution.

Comment: What you have tried?show your code

Comment: Did you solve this? I am trying to do the same thing and the answer here didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

First get the device token and store it to the database,and later it can be used for sending push-notification.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady(){
     //setting up for android
     if(PushbotsPlugin.isAndroid()){
        PushbotsPlugin.initializeAndroid("PUSHBOTS_APP_ID", "GCM_SENDER_ID");
    }
     //get the device token
    PushbotsPlugin.getToken(function(token){
        console.log(token);
    //setup an ajax request to store the device token
     $.ajax({
      url:'register.php',
      method:"POST",
      data:{token :token},
      success:function(data){
        console.log("from server"+data);
      },
      error:function(err){
       console.log("error"+err);   
     }
    });

    });
}
```

**register.php**

```
 <?php 
    $token=$_POST['token'];
   //setup database query for store the token
   if($query==true){
    echo 'success';
    }else{
      echo 'error';
    }
  ?>
```

Also replace `PUSH_BOT_APP_ID` and `GCM_SENDER_ID` with your values

Comment: Hi Shammon, I am not able to get the token. I tried to display the token by document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML=token; but still it not working. Please advise.